# Protected HTML / CSS for js?. I can not change some attributes on running time

Tags: javascript, html, css

For business reasons (endless discussion about blog colours), we want to give "some tool" to the user (sort of techie) to play with the colour themselves.

[The blog](http://leonliterariowp.azurewebsites.net/) is a simple Wordpress and has some plugins (i.e. Google Calendar embedded with an iframe).

We ask the user to play in the address bar with sentences like:

```
javascript:document.getElementById("reply-title").style.cssText='color:#f0555f';  void 0
```

While this works and modifies the text colour of the selected element (the "leave a comment" text), it doesn't work for other elements, specifically one of the elements belonging to the Google Calendar iframe (the following is the date that appears on top of the calendar):

```
javascript:document.getElementById("currentDate1").style.cssText='color:#f0555f';  void 0
```

Is it possible that the items inside the iframe are in some way **protected** of being changed by JavaScript?

Comment: It's very possible, it's called the [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy)

Comment: Why not right click on the element in question, "Inspect Element", check the CSS properties, click on the color and up pops a nice color selector to interactively play around with...? http://imgur.com/pwr6KIn

Comment: If it's the iframe, you're looking in the wrong place: the element is not in `document`, but in `iframe.contentWindow.document`. (and you're still blocked by SOP: `Blocked a frame with origin "http://leonliterariowp.azurewebsites.net" from accessing a cross-origin frame.`)

Comment: @adeneo surely from the user's URL input anything on the page can be manipulated.

Comment: anything inside an iframe is a completely SEPARATE document and won't be reachable via `document.whatever()`.

Comment: What @Amadan said is correct, but in this particular case it'll throw protocol mismatch error (the google calendar frame has `https` but the parent `http`). EDIT: after switching the parent to https it's "Uncaught SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin ... from accessing a frame with origin .... Protocols, domains, and ports must match"

Comment: @Pointy - sure, if you altered the iFrame's URL, but could you change stuff in a cross origin iFrame by changing the parent window URL? Never tried that, but I wouldn't think so?

Comment: @adeneo well you certainly can do it via Greasemonkey or anything else like that, or the developer tools. I guess it depends on how the browser launches the JavaScript - if it considers it to be part of the outer page, then I suppose you could be right.

Comment: Thanks every one, I totally forgot about the SOP policy, upsss

Sure I am doing very inefficiently, but in this way, it can give a code with all the change at once (opposite to play in the CSS inspect element, which by the way is how the client finds the properties to change)

Thanks to all to refresh me first class of IT  _embarrassed smile_

Answer (score 5):

Well actually... you are doing it very inefficiently.

If you have Chrome, Firefox, Internet Explorer, Opera or... Safari: 
you can "Right Click" on an element of the page an inspect the [DOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Object_Model).

And the styling (CSS). It will be more user-friendly even for Devz.

The items in an iFrame aren't protected from this.

For chrome, check [chrome devtools](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools).

EDIT: Also try pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>RightClick</kbd> if people are blocking it ;)

Comment: Thanks every one, I totally forgot about the SOP policy, upsss

Sure I am doing very inefficiently, but in this way, it can give a code with all the change at once (opposite to play in the CSS inspect element, which by the way is how the client finds the properties to change)

Thanks to all to refresh me first class of IT  _embarrassed smile_